# Excel VBA - populating Variant array increase memory usage

Tags: arrays, excel, memory, variant, vba

I'm new here and sorry in advance if my question was answered already, but I am searching for several days now and found no solution or explanation yet.

The problem is that during population of a variant array memory consumption constantly rises. The array is dimensioned, and when it is first dimensioned, I can see how memory consumption increases by a corresponding amount. I think a small piece of code will explain it better than words:

```
Sub test()
Dim Arr(1 To 1000000, 1 To 10) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000000
    For j = 1 To 10
        Arr(i, j) = "AAAAAAAAA"
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

My experience with this code is - after array dimensioning memory cons. increases by approx. 160 MB (which is 10*1 000 000 * 16). After the execution has finished I have and additional increase by about 400 MB! Interestingly - if you replace the string AAAA by a number, this problem vanishes.

In the actual program (this is just a test code) I have a bigger array of approx. 600 MB, but at the end of code execution memory usage is 3.4 GB! As a consequence an "Out of memory" error.

Can anyone please explain this?

Thanks in advance,
Den

Comment: Why do you find it surprising that when you put strings in an array, the memory used to store that array increases? The string itself isn't stored in the memory of the variant variable. In any event, Excel VBA is probably the wrong tool for data of that size. Perhaps using something like R (which can interact with Excel if you want to keep a certain front-end) might be a good strategic move.

Comment: I'm kind of bound to excel for this task. I did not expect the memory consumption to grow, because I declared the array, so I was expecting it will reserve the necessary memory, which is 16 Bytes for a variant times columns times rows, which in this case is 160 MB, and I can see +160 MB in task manager, when the array is declared. But during the execution memory usage rises till I have another 400 Mb, so in total 660 Mb for that array size? And why is memory consumption not increasing, when filling array with doubles? I saw the proposed topic, but the link I will read, thanks.

Comment: why use confusing variants in the first place? If you need string, use string array, same logic if long....

Comment: My argument was that I need to write it to worksheet, and if you write string array to worksheet, then values stay as text. Small problem, but I thought using Variant instead solves that for me automatically, so why not... Anyway, now using string, will optimize further in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is caused by the fact that when a variant contains a string, the actual string data is not stored internally. A variant consists of 16 bytes. The layout of those 16 bytes is described [here](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/). Note that 8 of those bytes contain things like type information and the other 8 contain the actual data *when that data is numerical*. When the data is a string, those 8 bytes are not enough. Instead, those 8 bytes contains a pointer to a [BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx) structure which consists of 4 bytes holding the length of a string, the actual characters in the string (with 2 bytes per character) and a 2-character null terminator. For your string of length 9, that works out to 24 bytes, hence a total of 16 + 24 = 40 bytes for storing that string (and the variant that it points to). This explains why it takes at least 400 MB to store those 10 million strings when you store them that way.

As you can see, variants are a memory hog. If you really need to use Excel VBA for this, you should avoid arrays of variants like a plague. Strings themselves are not very efficient. Perhaps you can do something like store the ascii codes for the characters as bytes or combine many strings into a single string which can be split when needed.

Comment: John, thank you very much for a simple and clear explanation! It makes a ton of sense now. I knew basically that variants are bad and inefficient, but I didn't know they are so bad. My data is actually mostly numeric, it just contains headers for data columns. It was just simpler to use the variant in this case, one of the reasons being that I get the data by reading the text file as binary, so that I get a string, which I split and write to the variant array. But since it creates problems, I guess I will have to use a small string array for headers and a separate double array for data.

Comment: John, if you have a range on the sheet that you are pulling data from, is it preferable to have that data stored in a range variable or a variant? When I bring in the data, I can do either (1) set rng = ws.range("name") or (2) var = ws.range("name").value2. As long as I am not manipulating any properties of the range on the sheet, I assumed that approach (2) was preferable for memory usage reasons, but I don't actually know that.

Comment: @Physco11 Approach 1 is preferable for memory, approach 2 is preferable for speed. There is an overhead in pulling data from a worksheet. Approach 2 does it just once. I almost always use the second approach. Memory usage is seldom an issue for me, but VBA is a slow language, and anything that can be done to speed it up is a plus. Also, I think that the resulting code is cleaner -- straightforward VBA code which deals with internal arrays (once you get the data), rather than code which is constantly interacting with the spreadsheet.

Comment: I agree with your approach, John. I learned to use ranges early in my VBA career, so I continued to use them out of habit, not because they were the best option. Now I prefer to make wrapper functions to extract values from ranges, do whatever manipulations or calculations I need on the internal arrays, then pass back to the ranges if I need to.